# How to change primeNG select button color dynamically according to the option selected by the user

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm using the p-selectButton from PrimeNG and I would like to know if it's possible to change the color of the button according to the option selected by the user. For example:

[image]

If user selects "Off" button turns red and if user selects "On", button turns green. The class that I need to change color is called "p-highlight". The problem is I don't know how to access this class because it seems the tag `<p-selectButton>` creates a div with p-highlight class, so I don't think it's possible to use `[styleClass]` or `[ngClass]` here.

[image]

Anyway to change this css class when user selects an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by overriding the css classes, it's not ideal since ng-deep is depricated ( for many years already but it still works )

```
::ng-deep {
      div[aria-labelledby='Off'].p-highlight {
        background: red;
      }
    
      div[aria-labelledby='On'].p-highlight {
        background: green;
      }
    }
```

An improvement would be to add a class/id to your component and then wrap this CSS due to how ng-deep works (see the StackBlitz code for an example).

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cubah1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fselect-button-basic-demo.scss)

[image][image]

Comment: ty @Mathias it worked pretty well...